# Change TMPDIR for Android shell script

Tags: shell

I am working on a script that will be run from an android shell (e.g. `adb shell`). I have a problem with writing temporary files, as this demonstrates:

```
$ cat <<-EOF > foo
> EOF
sh: can't create temporary file /data/local/shd1v7x1.tmp: Permission denied
```

I want to direct the shell's temporary directory to somewhere that is writable. I would usually do this:

```
$ export TMPDIR=/path/to/somwehere/writable
$ cat <<-EOF > foo
```

but it makes no difference.

Is it possible to specify the location the shell should use for temporary files?

(I know that running as `root` is a work around but that isn't a solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/data/local/tmp` should be writable on all Android and it works with that :-).

```
export TMPDIR=/data/local/tmp
```

Comment: yes, that works. I guess I must not have known of that location when I asked the question but I [know about it now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105574).